# How can I make a mutating iterator for a trait with implementors that persist data to disk, database, etc?

Tags: rust

I have a trait `MyVecTrait` with operations similar to a vec where trait implementors persist data to disk, database, cache, etc.

My goal is to add a `many_iter_mut()` function to the trait that accepts a list of indexes and returns a mutating iterator that calls `get()` and `set()` on the implementor.

I think I may be close, but am bumping into a compiler lifetime error.  Upon investigation, I find that this is normal when building mutating iterators, and normally an unsafe block is used to access data directly.  In my case the data ultimately lives elsewhere (eg on disk) so I must call the implementor's `set()` method.

To facilitate discussion, I provide the following code:

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;
use std::iter::Iterator;

pub type Index = u64;

// Trait that defines some Vec operations.
pub trait MyVecTrait<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    fn get(&self, index: Index) -> Option<&T>;
    fn get_mut(&mut self, index: Index) -> Option<MySetter<Self, T>> {
        // can this clone on indexes by avoided?
        if let Some(value) = self.get(index).cloned() {
            Some(MySetter {
                vec: self,
                index,
                value,
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
    fn set(&mut self, index: Index, value: T);

    /// return mutable iterator for elements matching indices
    fn many_iter_mut(
        &mut self,
        indices: impl IntoIterator<Item = Index> + 'static,
    ) -> ManyIterMut<Self, T>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        ManyIterMut {
            data: self,
            indices: indices.into_iter().collect(),  // avoid collect if possible.
            phantom: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}

// This is a simple NewType that just wraps Vec and implements
// MyVecTrait.  A real-world impl would persist data to
// cache, file system, database, etc.

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SimpleVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T: Clone> MyVecTrait<T> for SimpleVec<T> {
    fn get(&self, index: Index) -> Option<&T> {
        self.0.get(index as usize)
    }

    fn set(&mut self, index: Index, value: T) {
        self.0[index as usize] = value;
    }
}

// a mutating iterator for types that impl MyVecTrait
pub struct ManyIterMut<'a, V, T>
where
    V: MyVecTrait<T> + ?Sized,
    T: Clone,
{
    indices: BTreeSet<Index>, // Can this be a generic iterator?
    data: &'a mut V,

    phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<'a, V, T: 'a> Iterator for ManyIterMut<'a, V, T>
where
    V: MyVecTrait<T>,
    T: Clone,
{
    type Item = MySetter<'a, V, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(i) = self.indices.iter().next() {
            self.data.get_mut(*i)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

/// setter returned from get_mut() and many_iter_mut()
/// use this to inspect and modify values.
pub struct MySetter<'a, V, T>
where
    V: MyVecTrait<T> + ?Sized,
    T: Clone,
{
    vec: &'a mut V,
    index: Index,
    value: T,
}

impl<'a, V, T> MySetter<'a, V, T>
where
    V: MyVecTrait<T> + ?Sized,
    T: Clone,
{
    pub fn set(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.vec.set(self.index, value);
    }

    pub fn value(&self) -> &T {
        &self.value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = SimpleVec(vec![100, 200, 300, 400, 500]);

    for mut setter in v.many_iter_mut([2, 3, 5]) {
        let val = setter.value();
        setter.set(*val + 1)
    }

    println!("modified vec: {:?}", v);
}
```

that fails to compile with error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:79:13
   |
70 | impl<'a, V, T: 'a> Iterator for ManyIterMut<'a, V, T>
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
77 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
78 |         if let Some(i) = self.indices.iter().next() {
79 |             self.data.get_mut(*i)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
```

See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7194a6980e9773e3599ed9d32d56fa8d).

So can my code be fixed?  Or else how would you approach it?

Comment: You're trying to return a mutable reference to the first item in `v` over and over, that's UB, of course the compiler doesn't allow that. `self.indices.iter().next()` returns the same index every time because it recreates the iterator! Did you mean to use `self.indices.pop_first()`? But `ManyIterMut` also holds on to the mutable reference so it can't return it.

Comment: You could look at the as of yet unstable [`slice::get_many_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get_many_mut) for inspiration. Turning that into an iterator should be straight forward.

Comment: yeah if I change it to use `pop_first()` I still get the same lifetime error.   Also `slice::get_many_mut` is kinda interesting and I had looked at it before, but they are just returning an array and working directly with memory.   I need a level of indirection, as explained in the original question.

Comment: Yes that's because `ManyIterMut` can't hold on to and return an exclusive reference which your implementation does.

Comment: Nitpick: The `'static` bound on the iterator is unnecessary, since you're collecting it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write this iterator generically, sadly. Individual implemetors might be able to provide their own, or you can do that with [lending iterators](https://docs.rs/lending-iterator).

Comment: thx.  I took a quick look at lending-iterators and it is not obvious to me how to use it for this purpose.

Comment: @danda Like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=840d9b3d4e3026839f1e963587ecb5de. At this point, I don't know if the trait has any advantage over just a simple `next()` method, but if eventually lending iterators will make themselves into std, and especially if there will be syntax sugar for them, it'll be worth it.

Comment: that's very nice, thank-you!   Finally, it runs!     One little thing though, I notice that if I try to use ManyIterMut as an actual iterator, the compiler complains it is not an iterator.   Is there any way to fix that, do you think?    [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd5295e7064ad52a51749ee13fff0204)

Comment: @danda No. Lending iterators have no support from the compiler.